# APPLICATION_NAME doesn't run in shell script in Code Deploy AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-ec2

I am having a script for my nodejs application called application_start.sh and the script contains below detials. I am running the script using appspec.yml which points to the application_start. The problem i am facing is, it can never identify or execute "APPLICATION_NAME" and hence it never goes inside any of the 3 if loops. APPLICATION_NAME is the application name of the deployment group, and i made sure that they are correct in the script. I am not sure i any dependency is needed to be installed or something else. I am also not sure if there is a way to do just $APPLICATION_NAME inside ssh and find out if the value comes back or not because current it doesnt show me anything.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'run application_start.sh: ' >> /home/ec2-user/bv-server/deploy.log

echo 'pm2 restart bv-server-app' >> /home/ec2-user/bv-server/deploy.log
sudo pm2 restart bv-server-app >> /home/ec2-user/bv-server/deploy.log

DIR=/home/ec2-user/bv-server/environments
echo '$APPLICATION_NAME'
#create config directory if not exists
mkdir $DIR -p
echo '$APPLICATION_NAME' >> /home/ec2-user/bv-server/deploy.log
if [[ "$APPLICATION_NAME" == *"XYZ-Server-STAGING" ]];
then
#here we are assuming that the EC2 has a role for accessing the S3 bucket
sudo aws s3 cp s3://secrets-bucket/nodejs-app/staging $DIR --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.env-stage"
elif [[ "$APPLICATION_NAME" == *"XYZ-Server-QA" ]];
then
sudo aws s3 cp s3://secrets-bucket/nodejs-app/qa $DIR --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.env-test"
elif [[ "$APPLICATION_NAME" == "XYZ-Server-Prod" ]];
then
echo 'I am here'
sudo aws s3 cp s3://env-bv-server/prod $DIR --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.env-prod"
fi
```

Comment: Where is the value of `APPLICATION_NAME` set?  Clearly it is not set by this script, so it must be set somewhere else.  Where?

Comment: Its set in Code Deploy of AWS. because aws deploy list-applications show me that APPLICATION_NAME

Comment: According to the documentation, you have to set APPLICATION_NAME in the console or AWS CLI.  Did you do that?  If so, how?

Comment: Yes because i get below details:{
    "application": {
        "applicationName": "WordPress_App",
        "applicationId": "a1b2c3d4-5678-90ab-cdef-11111EXAMPLE",
        "createTime": 1407878168.078,
        "linkedToGitHub": false
    }
} on running below command :  aws deploy get-application --application-name WordPress_App